# Find previous MongoDB --dpath save location

Tags: mongodb

I previously launched `mongod --dpath` with a specific directory and I'm having trouble locating it after a computer restart. Is there any way to find a previous directory path that was used?

I'm not using the default path of `/data/db` as when I run `mongod` I get `NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found.`

A few of the databases had over 5gb so I don't want to recreate them in `/data/db`

Answer (score 0):

I utilized the find command to search for the collection files that are generated by mongoDB

`find / -name 'collection-*.wt'`